# Send TCP messages at certain rate with Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, tcp, load, traffic

I am trying to generate some traffic to a server by sending TCP messages to it.
For this, I am using a Python script which opens a TCP socket and then sends some data over it. After receiving a reply, the TCP connection gets closed.

Question: I would like to be able to predefine a rate with which the script will be sending the requests to the server, eg: 5 messages per second. However, I do not have a clue how to script this via Python :(.

Anyone an idea how to do this (a short example would be super ! ;) ?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I might need to add an extra difficulty: since the server has to reply,
I guess I have to make the script working asynchronously ... That way, I can
send the requests out without having to wait for a reply on the previous request...

Comment: Some questions to hopefully improve the question:

1) 5 messages per second.  Do you want to send all 5 at once (or close to it) and then wait the remaining portion each second, or did you want to send them 200 ms apart

2) Do you want to need to worry about TCP stuff (i.e. if you send a message but it takes several retries to actually get across the network), does your script want to add extra delay?

3) Does it have to be python?  I'm a big fan of Python, but depending on your use case, something like JMeter (java-based) might be a better way to go

Comment: Hi Foon, already thanks for the fast response ! Some more info: 1) maybe the easiest would be to make it 200ms apart ? 2) I would like to get to know when these kind of delays occur (maybe I can build it in the script). 3) JMeter might be a help, but it gives me less control than building a script myself ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an implementation of the [token bucket algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket). It's analogous to a bucket with a fixed capacity, where each consumer can't perform the action until it gets a token, and the bucket is refilled at a fixed rate.

The algorithm is easy to implement, but the link below has an example:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511490-implementation-of-the-token-bucket-algorithm/